# Slash problem with Doxygen filter under MSYS2

Tags: linux, windows, doxygen, msys2

I am using doxygen with a python filter.
On the top level I have a bash script calling doxygen with a template file in folder **res** (template.doxyfile).
Inside the folder **res** there is a filter script (doxyfilter.py) as well.

The top level script runs under MSYS2/Windows 10 and under Linux.

Everything worked fine but recently I receive the error "**res**" cannot be found.

I invoke the filter with:

```
INPUT_FILTER           = res/doxyfilter.py<br>
```

which works on Linux.
On MSYS2 there is no warning or output and debugging tells me:

```
D:/doxy/xxx/XXX.cpp...
Executing popen(res/doxyfilter.py "D:/xxx/XXX.cpp")
```

On MSYS2 it is working recently with

```
INPUT_FILTER           = res\doxyfilter.py<br>
```

but I don't want to change it because of it will break the Linux version.
This command results in debug output under MSYS2:

```
Preprocessing D:/doxy/xxx/XXX.cpp...
Executing popen(res\doxyfilter.py "D:/doxy/xxx/XXX.cpp")
```

Doxygen version used: 1.9.3

Can anyone tell me a solution.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What do you see when invoking doxygen as `doxygen -d extcmd` on both platforms?

Comment: Doxygen version used: 1.9.3

With
`INPUT_FILTER           = res\doxyfilter.py`
I get
`Preprocessing D:/doxy/xxx/XXX.cpp...`<br>
`Executing popen(`res\doxyfilter.py "D:/doxy/xxx/XXX.cpp"`)`
whitch generates a good output.

Changed to 
`INPUT_FILTER           = res/doxyfilter.py* 
results in
`Preprocessing D:/doxy/xxx/XXX.cpp...`<br>
`Executing popen(`res/doxyfilter.py "D:/xxx/XXX.cpp"`)`
and the output is emty and warnings are raised (the command "res" is wrong written or could not be found).

All in a MSYS2 environment.

Comment: Please add the results from the comment into the question. Which compiler are you using with MKSYS2?

Comment: Did you try to use `INPUT_FILTER="python res/doxyfiletr.py"`?

Comment: ```INPUT_FILTER="python res/doxyfiletr.py"´´´ is working. Thank you.